# How can I find the general term for this derivative?

Tags: calculus

I want to find the general term for the nth derivative of (where x=0):

$\frac{x^2}{\left(x-1\right)^2}$ , $x=0$

Wolfram alpha gives me the direct answer:

$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}$$\left(\frac{x^2}{\left(x-1\right)^2}\right) = (n-1)n!$$,n\ge1$

How do I get to this answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2} = x^2 \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)
\end{align}
then Taylor expand.